# Data undefined at Node.js from AngularJS POST request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am attempting to send a fairly simple POST request to my server using AngularJS. The request goes through and hits my controller on the back end, but for some reason `req.data` is showing up as `undefined`.

**Front End Controller:**

```
function CardDirectiveController($http, $scope) {
    var self = this;

    self.addToFavorites = function() {
        let card = {
            id: $scope.$id,
            attack : $scope.attack,
            cost: $scope.cost,
            img: $scope.img,
            name: $scope.name,
            class: $scope.class,
            rarity: $scope.rarity,
            type: $scope.type
        }

        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/card',
            data: card
        })
    };
}
angular.module('cardDirective').controller('CardDirectiveController', CardDirectiveController);
```

**Server**

```
'use strict';

let express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    router = require('./routes/sampleRouter'),
    cardRouter = require('./routes/cardRouter');


let app = express();

// Serve any requests for static files (like index.html)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/')));

// Use any routing rules found in the router file
app.use('/', router);
app.use('/card', cardRouter)



app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Application live and running on port: ' + PORT);
});
```

**Router:**

```
'use strict';

let express = require('express'),
    cardController = require('./../controllers/cardController');

let router = express.Router();

router.route('/').post(cardController.postCard);
router.route('/:cardName').get(cardController.showCards);


module.exports = router;
```

**Back End Controller**

```
'use strict';

let cardController = {
    showCards: showCards,
    postCard: postCard
};

module.exports = cardController


function showCards(req, res) {
    console.log('showCards ', req.params.cardName);
    res.end()
}

function postCard(req, res) {
    console.log('postCard ', req.url, req.method, req.data)
    res.end()
}
```

The response I am getting in the console from making this request is `postCard / POST undefined`. Console logging the `card` object returns the expected result. I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I've been stuck for a while now.

Comment: please use body-parser middleware in your app.js..
```https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `bodyParser` middleware to parse request body.

Install the `body-parser` module:

```
$ npm install body-parser
```

Configure it in app.js :

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

In your controller use `req.body` instead of `req.data`:

```
function postCard(req, res) {
   console.log('postCard ', req.url, req.method, req.body);
   res.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use body-parser in your app.js file.
Change your server.js file to following code

```
    'use strict';

    let express = require('express'),
        path = require('path'),
        router = require('./routes/sampleRouter'),
        cardRouter = require('./routes/cardRouter'),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser');




    let app = express();

    // Serve any requests for static files (like index.html)
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/')));
    // parse application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    // Use any routing rules found in the router file
    app.use('/', router);
    app.use('/card', cardRouter)



    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log('Application live and running on port: ' + PORT);
    });
```